# jquery, changing form action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, action

i cannot seem to find the answer to this. i uploaded code to pastebin (so wouldnt clutter up the post):

http://pastebin.com/BhnNTnJM

but the action only changes for the delete form (id=form-horse-delete) and not the other 2 forms located on the page.  i am at my wits end trying to figure out why it doesn't work for the 2 forms, yet will work for the 1 form.

in IE, if i try and change the action of the 2 forms, it gives a javascript error.  but if i take out the change, it works fine with no javascript error.

Comment: Validator told me there seems to be extra div in the end – potential error source.

Comment: yeah, probably because i took out alot of the html that didn't pertain to the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an input field called **action** in the form-horse-update and form-horse-add forms. e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
```

**action** is kind of a reserved word, as having an input field with that name changes the behaviour of the form.  Normally in JavaScript (let alone jQuery) a reference to something like:

```
document.myform.action
```

refers to the action attribute of the form.  The minute you add an input field called action then instead the above would refer to the input element called action and there is no longer a way to access the form's action attribute.

The best solution is to rename your **action** input fields to something else (but probably best not to rename it to **submit**! ;) )

Comment: yeah, i also just found that myself playing around with the form.  thanks !