# How to '$_POST' back to the same page or to a different result page in php?

Tags: php, post

I wrote a php file **Calculator.php** that posts result to **info.php**, and I wrote another php file - **Calculator2.php** that posts results to the same page. How can I combine them together? I tried to put one after another and it doesnt work.

**Calculator.php**

```
<FORM action="info.php" method="post">
<P>
<LABEL for="firstNum">First Number: </LABEL>
<INPUT type="text" name="firstNum" id="firstNumberLabel"><BR>
<LABEL for="secondNum">Second Number: </LABEL>
<INPUT type="text" name="secondNum" id="secondNumberlabel"><BR>

<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="1"> Add<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="2"> Subtract<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="3"> Multiply<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="4"> Divide<BR>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Send">
<INPUT type="reset">
</P>
</FORM>
```

**info.php file**

```
<?php

switch ($_POST["calc"]){
case "1":
 echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']+$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
case "2":
 echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']-$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
case "3":
 echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']*$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
case "4":
 echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']/$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
default:
 break;
}
?>
```

**Calculator2.php**

```
<form action= <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> method="post">
    <label for="text_field">First Number: </LABEL>
    <input type="text" name="user_text" id="text_field"><BR>
    <label for="text_field2">Second Number: </LABEL>
    <input type="text" name="user_text2" id="text_field2"><BR>

 <input type="submit" value="Add">

 </form>

 <?php
   if(isset($_POST['user_text'])&&isset($_POST['user_text2']))
   echo $_POST['user_text']+$_POST['user_text2'];
 ?>
```

Comment: Show us your code... maybe we can help you.

Without see your code we can't help you.

Comment: Thank you Sena, I just added the code, please take a look if you got a chance!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996806/can-one-form-have-multiple-actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<FORM action="info.php" method="post">
 <P>
 <LABEL for="firstNum">First Number: </LABEL>
 <INPUT type="text" name="firstNum" id="firstNumberLabel"><BR>
 <LABEL for="secondNum">Second Number: </LABEL>
<INPUT type="text" name="secondNum" id="secondNumberlabel"><BR>

<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="1"> Add<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="2"> Subtract<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="3"> Multiply<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="4"> Divide<BR>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Send">
<INPUT type="reset">
</P>
</FORM>


<form action= <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?> method="post">
<label for="text_field">First Number: </LABEL>
<input type="text" name="firstNum" id="text_field"><BR>
<label for="text_field2">Second Number: </LABEL>
<input type="text" name="secondNum" id="text_field2"><BR>

<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="1"> Add<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="2"> Subtract<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="3"> Multiply<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="calc" value="4"> Divide<BR>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Send">


</form>


<?php
 switch ($_POST["calc"]){
case "1":
 echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']+$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
case "2":
 echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']-$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
case "3":
 echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']*$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
case "4":
 echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']/$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
default:
break;
}
?>
```

and with the same info.php as before

```
<?php
 switch ($_POST["calc"]){
case "1":
 echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']+$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
case "2":
 echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']-$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
case "3":
echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']*$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
case "4":
echo "Result: ", $_POST['firstNum']/$_POST['secondNum'], "<br>";
 break;
default:
 break;
}
?>
```

the problem with it is i think there is quite a lot of repeated code

Answer (score 0):

Insert your data into the below brackets where needed.

```
<?php
if(sizeof($_POST) == 0){
    // echo html here
}
else{
    // Perform php actions here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it didn't work that way and I just added the code, would you be open to take a look again?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat solution. Add a common script which process the submission of form and then redirect it with result to wherever require.

Comment: Thanks @Aakash I just learned php a week ago, I am actually not sure about what you are saying. Can you give me an example?