# Can I have more actions in a form?

Tags: php, forms, authentication, action

As I said in the title I need more than 1 action in a form...
The form is for a log in script and it's like this:

```
<form method="post" action="action.php" name="loginform" id="loginform">
 <br><br>
       Username:<br> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br><br>
       Password:<br><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br /><br>
        <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login"  class="page"/>

        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="register.php" class="page">Sign up</a>

    </form>
```

The action.php page is like this:

```
<?php
  include('index.php');
  include('insert.php');
  include('contact.php');
  include('about.php');
?>
```

it seems to work the way I want it mostly but after I hit the log in button it redirects me to action.php page which includes all the pages above...
I need this action.php page because if I log in I want to be logged in on all pages, not just one of them.
Can I have it redirect to another page or something?

Comment: What about using sessions? There is no need for having  actions which is not possible.

Comment: I don't know how to use them

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: O checked that http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php and there doesn't seem to be anything helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can one form have multiple actions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996806/can-one-form-have-multiple-actions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect to another page from action.php by using the [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

and adding this line to your code

```
header("Location:www.yourpage.com");
```

> Note: I have used redirect because you said you don't know how to use sessions.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work. it probably redirect me before logging me up. and if I put it after the includes it gives me an error.

Comment: Warning: cannot modify header information - headers already sent by(output stated at folder path\index.php:13) in forder path\action.php on line 8

Comment: it somehow works now. I might have done something wrong the first time I did this... thanks a lot.

Comment: add _ob_start()_ to the first line of action.php

Answer (score 0):

I read that you don't know how to use sessions. Well, I created a Session Wrapper object for my framework. You can learn from it, use it as a base or download it and implement it in your project: https://github.com/yagarasu/crinoline/blob/master/0.1.0a/cr-core/Session.class.php

Hope this helps.